# Request for ability to disable lowered ad privileged

Tags: feature-request

After reaching a specific reputation milestone you earn the privilege to have a reduced amount of ads. I personally don't mind ads and want to be able to disable this privilege for two reasons:

1. I want to support the site as much as I can (to show appreciation for how much it has helped me)
2. I actually find the advertisements on Stackoverflow and the other site relevant and useful for me.

I know this may seem like a weird, absurd or abnormal request and that very few people may actually use it but if people are willing to support the site to that extent why not let them (unless the advertisement network requires specific demographics, unique visitors, etc.)

Comment: you can: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273652/choose-to-see-reduced-ads-or-not/275687#275687

Comment: @PatrickHaugh wow you're a ninja! I Googled but didn't find an answer. Thank you